# Not getting same type from localStorage as the saved variable had?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, local-storage

I wrote a simple task list. The JavaScript code is below, the important part is about localStorage. What I made so far is this: [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/cobozunova/edit?html,js,output)

What i want to achieve is that when i reload the page, the setting if the entries should be removed immediately (if the checkbox next to the textfield is checked or not), is saved and restored from the last visit.

Currently when I first load the page I need to uncheck and then check the checkbox again in order to make it work as I want it...

Here is my JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
var anzahl = 0;
var autoremove = true;
var autoremove_backup = localStorage.getItem("autoremove");
console.log(localStorage.getItem("autoremove"));

$(document).ready(function() {
  if(autoremove_backup===false){
    $("#autoremove").prop( "checked", false);
  }
  else if (autoremove_backup===true){
    $("#autoremove").prop( "checked", true);
  }
  autoremove = autoremove_backup;
  setInterval(entry, 2000);
  $("button").on('click', function() {
    if(this.id=="add"){
      var r = $('<div id="'+ "div"+String(anzahl) +'"><input type="checkbox" id="'+String(anzahl)+'">' + '<label for="'+ String(anzahl)+'" id="'+ "label" +String(anzahl)+'">' + $("#task").val() + '</label><br></div>');
      $("#var").append(r);
      anzahl = anzahl +1;
    }
  });
  $('input[type=checkbox]').change(
    function(){
      if (this.checked) {
        if(String(this.id)==="autoremove"){
          autoremove=true;
          saveAutoremove(autoremove);
        }
      }
      else {
        if(String(this.id)==="autoremove"){
          autoremove=false;
          saveAutoremove(autoremove);
        }
      }
    });

});

function entry(){
if(autoremove===true){
  $('#var input:checked').each(function() {
    $("#div"+String(this.id)).remove();
});
}
}


function saveAutoremove(input){
  localStorage.setItem("autoremove", input);
}
```

Comment: EVERYTHING is stored as **string** in `localStorage`.

Comment: Ah thank you, I thought it might be some type problem...

Comment: When concatenating something to a string literal it isn't necessary to explicitly cast it to a string, it will implicitly be cast. You can write `"#div" + this.id`  instead of `"#div" + String(this.id)`. There might be times you want to be explicit just for clarity's sake but when the literal is on the left it should be pretty self evident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't working because:

1. When any value is stored in `localStorage` it is coerced to a string, so when you store the primitive values `true` or `false`, they are coerced to the strings `'true'` and `'false'`.
2. When you retrieve the value from `localStorage` it remains a string.
3. Your comparisons are using the strict `===` comparison operator when comparing a string to `true` or `false`, the result will always be `false`. Thus neither the `if` nor `else` clause will ever be true so the default `checked` attribute from the HTML remains. Note that using the non-strict `==` comparison would not have made the code work as intended. This is because the strings `'true'` and `'false'` both coerce to `true`. Thus the `else` branch would always be followed.

You can fix it by setting `autoremove_backup` based on the string value that you get back from `localStorage`:

```
var autoremove_backup = localStorage.getItem("autoremove") === 'true' ? true : false;
```

Another approach I've used in the past is to serialize/deserialize everything stored in `localStorage` with `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`.

To set it:

```
function saveAutoremove(input) {
  localStorage.setItem("autoremove", JSON.stringify(input));
}
```

To get it:

```
var autoremove_backup = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("autoremove"));
```

It adds a little bit of overhead, but it automatically converts booleans back to booleans.

Comment: The JSON approach also works with just about anything. It lets you store objects or arrays so long as their properties/elements can be stored by [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) (i.e. all properties are enumerable, don't contain functions, etc).